# Can the Mercurial merge-tools INI list be cleared? (Avoiding "couldn't find merge tool" spam.)

Tags: python, mercurial

Anytime I do a merge I prefer to use `-v` so I can visually/casually confirm the list of files as they're being processed.  Lately (now using Mercurial 5.5.1), I get a slew of pointless debugging noise as well:

```
resolving manifests
calling hook preupdate.eol: hgext.eol.preupdate
getting src/foo
getting src/bar
couldn't find merge tool ecmerge
couldn't find merge tool editmerge
couldn't find merge tool filemerge
couldn't find merge tool filemergexcode
couldn't find merge tool gpyfm
couldn't find merge tool kdiff3
couldn't find merge tool meld
couldn't find merge tool bcompare
couldn't find merge tool bcomposx
couldn't find merge tool UltraCompare
couldn't find merge tool araxis
couldn't find merge tool beyondcompare3
couldn't find merge tool diffuse
couldn't find merge tool diffmerge
couldn't find merge tool p4merge
couldn't find merge tool p4mergeosx
couldn't find merge tool tkdiff
couldn't find merge tool tortoisemerge
couldn't find merge tool xxdiff
couldn't find merge tool gvimdiff
couldn't find merge tool winmerge
couldn't find merge tool merge
couldn't find merge tool hgmerge
merging src/foo
couldn't find merge tool ecmerge
couldn't find merge tool editmerge
couldn't find merge tool filemerge
couldn't find merge tool filemergexcode
couldn't find merge tool gpyfm
couldn't find merge tool kdiff3
couldn't find merge tool meld
couldn't find merge tool bcompare
couldn't find merge tool bcomposx
couldn't find merge tool UltraCompare
couldn't find merge tool araxis
couldn't find merge tool beyondcompare3
couldn't find merge tool diffuse
couldn't find merge tool diffmerge
couldn't find merge tool p4merge
couldn't find merge tool p4mergeosx
couldn't find merge tool tkdiff
couldn't find merge tool tortoisemerge
couldn't find merge tool xxdiff
couldn't find merge tool gvimdiff
couldn't find merge tool winmerge
couldn't find merge tool merge
couldn't find merge tool hgmerge
merging src/bar
```

This gets dumped on every file, which is useless and unhelpful.  (I can see where this information would be good to know in the presence of `--debug`, but not merely `-v/--verbose` and certainly not repeated on every file!)

All of these tool entries are from `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/defaultrc/mergetools.rc` which is simply a long list of the standard Mercurial (well, Python) INI-format configuration block for `[merge-tools]`.

I have a single `[merge-tools]` entry in my own `.hgrc`, and that's the one I'm actually using during merges.  None of these builtin ones will ever be used, so I don't care if the corresponding executable hasn't been installed.

Is there a way to reset `[merge-tools]` to an empty list, prior to my own entry?  (I'm unfamiliar with the syntax rules of Python INI files, and the little googling I did only found actual Python code to do the list clearing, nothing that I could put into an `.hgrc` file.)  Barring that, is there some other trick to make a verbose merge operation be a little less dumb about repetitive noise?